# How to keep record of Trips made in a transportation company?

Tags: mysql, database, logging, model, uml

I want to keep track of trips made in a day.
I have the following tables using MySQL :

- route (routeID,start,destination,carId)
- user (userId,routeId,...)
- ticket (ticketID,routeID..)
- car (carID,ownerID)
- owner (ownerID..)

So my problem I want to keep a record of trips made in a day for example that includes users who bought a ticket being transported on a specified route by a car owned by Owner, to be shown as History for admin, car owner, and users.

Maybe a query with INNER JOIN Might show me what I want but it won't record anything, so what is the best MODEL/table structure that fits this situation.

I hope I made this as clear as it can.
Thank you very much for your consideration.

Comment: a ticket does not have information about date/time the trip starts and ends ?

Comment: there is no tripID nor nothing else about a table trip in your question ....

Comment: What have you tried so far? And where did you get stuck in your progress?

Comment: Definitely you should show the attempts you have made so far. Also, there is a difference between making a model that shows your data structure and queries that are actual pieces of code. It might be good to have the model first so as you understand your data.

Comment: I m sorry for any obscurity any my post. I was wondering how would you define the table that stores the records of every trip made daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a transport company, I understand the `route` being a regular service.  To solve your problem, you have to:

- identify occurrences of a `route` on a given day.
- associate somehow the `users` to the `ticket` they have bought.

The solution will depend on what you already have.

### In the database

**Case 1**: If the `ticket` is for a specific date, you already addressed the first point. If the `ticket` is emitted for a `user` you solved the second point. In this case your trip is an inner join of the `user` with the `ticket` and the `route` (and with any other table containing relevant data of interest). No recording is needed. In the DB you’d solve this with a CREATE VIEW that would always be up-to date.

**Case 2**: If any of the above condition is not met (e.g ticket without a date, or anonymous tickets), you’d need to add a `trip` table that provides the missing information, for example `routeId, userId, ticketId, date_of_travel`. You would also CREATE a VIEW to join this data with the other tables and make all the relevant data of interest always available.

### In your model:

In the first case you’d have to do nothing in an ER model since the trip is already there (in the ticket probably). But in an UML class diagram you can show a trip class that is associated with the others to make visibility of data and relations explicit.

In the second case you’d add a many-to-many association between user and ticket, with an association class to hold the additional informations you need to record

Comment: Thank you kind Sir for this explicit answer. It really opened my eyes to the way I was looking to my concept.

Comment: As a side note (as I worked for German Rail for some time): ticketing systems are huge. And the worst part are the tarriffs. So the above is the shovel of sand from the beach you need to build.